# Tree data structure __str__ method

Tags: python, algorithm, oop, data-structures, tree

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self,data,children = []):
        self.data = data
        self.children = children


    def __str__(self,level=0):
        ret = " " * level + str(self.data) + '\n'
        for child in self.children:
           ret += child.__str__(level+1)

        return ret

    # adding the children to the tree node
    def addchildren(self,TreeNode):
        self.children.append(TreeNode)
```

**Ques1** : Please explain `def __str__(self,level=0):`. Especially `child.__str__(level+1)`

```
drinks = TreeNode('Drinks',[])
cold = TreeNode('Cold',[])
hot = TreeNode('Hot',[])
cola = TreeNode('Cola',[])
cappucino = TreeNode('Cappucino',[])
drinks.addchildren(cold)
drinks.addchildren(hot)
cold.addchildren(cola)
hot.addchildren(cappucino)

print(drinks)
```

**Ques 2**: And one more thing why is it giving this type error(given below) if I use `self.children.append(TreeNode.data)`, I know it's not gonna work but why the print( ) statement is throwing this error but not in `self.children.append(TreeNode)`. Why is it saying **expected 0 arguments, got 1** ?

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_944/4195955341.py in <module>
----> 1 print(drinks)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_944/3676504849.py in __str__(self, level)
      8         ret = " " * level + str(self.data) + '\n'
      9         for child in self.children:
---> 10             ret += child.__str__(level+1)
     11 
     12         return ret

TypeError: expected 0 arguments, got 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def __str__(self,level=0):
    ret = " " * level + str(self.data) + '\n'
    for child in self.children:
       ret += child.__str__(level+1)

    return ret
```

`" " * level` means repeat space level times. Default value for `level` is `0` for object itself and level plus one for children, these children again call `__str__` of theirs children with level increased by one. So current object has 0 spaces at start of its line, its' children 1 space at start of their lines, childrens of children 2 spaces at start of their lines and so on, which provides nice visual representation akin to what you might encounter when browsing catalogs e.g.:

```
rootdir
 dir1
  dir11
  dir12
 dir2
  dir21
  dir22
```

where dir11 and dir12 are inside dir1, dir21 and dir22 are inside dir2, dir1 and dir2 are inside rootdir.

It is uncommon for python `__str__` methods to have more than 1 argument (any argument beyond `self`). Say one of child is tuple `(1,2,3)` then when you try to print your tree, it does try to print that with level equal to `1`, that is

```
(1,2,3).__str__(1)
```